# POIs retrieving from JSON doesn't appear (Wikitude + Phonegap)

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, augmented-reality, wikitude

I have been working on a WIKITUDE-Phonegap app. The application is a location based AR app that shows the markers on the camera view when tilting the phone arounnd (Displaying POI label) The license I have is Educational license so that the app I am developing doesn't have unlicensed watermark on it.

The problem I am having now is that I want to use my own latitudes & longitudes and description of places instead of the random ones that app generates. I did everything following the Documentation about retrieving the data from JSON file (also commented out the code). However, when I built it to the device, the markers won't appear.

I am developing it on iOS 8.3 - Object-C based and test on iPhone 5.

Anyone has the same problem? How to solve this?

Any answers will be appreciated.

PS. excuse my English if you don't quite get what I tried to explain.

Thank you,

Scott

Comment: Please include the code that you have and is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. 
It appears that the locations I had added were too far from where my phone was located when I tested it. Now I am at the location, they all show up.

Thank you :)

Comment: You could use a relative location instead (as in the sample application)